# Changing Layout of Product Options in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm currently customizing the *bluescale* theme for Magento. I have moved the position of the "product options" box for configurable products from lower on the page to just under the title.

I am now trying to remove the 3 links below the add to cart button (add to wishlist, compare, and ask a question), but cannot figure out where to do so. Where can I find the template for the actual "product options" box? You can see the webpage here: http://bit.ly/xgFy2a

P.S. I can't simply delete the template file for the links, as they still appear elsewhere.

Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can debug your template locations by enabling Template Path Hints like this:

1. Open the admin control panel
2. Open the system tab and select configuration
3. Select Developer on the left sidebar
4. Select Main Website From the Current Configuration Scope Drop Down (upper left)
5. Open the debug dropdown
6. Set Template Path Hints To Yes

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find the file that is outputing the html. But I still cannot find the code that is causing this addto.phtml block to be added on the product option block. When I follow the code down to the wrapper all I can find is this line: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true);?> Any idea what I can do from here?Thanks, Brett

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I needed to edit the catalog.xml code in the default template to remove that line of code. Thanks for your help.